# chcp not recognized internal or external in Atom command terminal for Django

Tags: windows, cmd, atom-editor

I'm currently trying to learn Django with the Atom IDE. In Atom, I've installed the `platformio-ide-terminal` package.
I then created a django environment by typing in the Atom command terminal the following: `conda create --name MyDjangoEnv5`
I consistently get this message after trying to my initial attempt to use Django:

```
 C:\Users\Michael> activate MyDjangoEnv5

 "chcp" is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
  operable     program or batch file.
 "cmd" is not recognized as an internal or external command,
  operable program or batch file.
```

I installed Django in the Atom command terminal `conda install django` and the installation went perfectly fine.

I have looked up another stackoverflow link regarding this "chcp" not recognized issue, and didn't find it helpful or clear.

I tried checking my path by right clicking on my PC (I'm using Windows 8, 64-bit), and clicked on properties.
`Right-click "This PC" > Properties > Advanced system settings > Environment Variables...`

In `System variables` I added variable name as`PATH` and variable value as `C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe` and for `User variables for Michael` I added `C:\Windows\system32;` as `PATH`.

I then tried in a new Atom command terminal `activate MyDjangoEnv5` and still got the same `"chpc" is not recognized...` error again.

Can anyone please help? I'm completely stuck and until then I won't be able to build any websites using Django. The Atom command terminal works perfectly fine for Python though.

Comment: Seems you have messed around with the `PATH` variable; have you deleted or overwritten it somehow?

Comment: I added and changed some stuff a while back when doing an online course on connecting java to Unity 3D for making Android games. Honestly, I'm not sure what to do. Is there some sort of default path for User variables and System variables I could put it back to? I've looked on Google and YouTube, and not found any solutions.

Comment: So you cleared `PATH`? What is displayed when you enter `path` in a command prompt (`cmd`) window?

Comment: Type in `cmd` where? Manoeuvre to `C:\Windows\System32` in Explorer and run `cmd.exe`; if it is not there, then it's really bad...

Comment: Yeah, i managed to find cmd.exe as a command terminal (as in a black window, essentially) in the C:\Windows\system32 path. I thought you meant in the Environment variables. When I type in `cmd` it works perfectly though. And if I type in `where chcp` I get back `C:\Windows\System32\chcp.com`

Comment: You misconfigured the system `PATH`. Remove the user value, and add the following for the system value: `%SystemRoot%\System32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0`.